# Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, linq, many-to-many

I have  nurse and patient tables having a many to many relationship; thus, the third relationship table is nurse_patient consisting of n_id and p_id.

Once a nurse logins a session is created. I want to select all patients of this logged in nurse only. I tried the code below but it's giving the error shown in the title.

```
if (Session["LogedUserID"] != null)
{
   int p = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LogedUserID"]);
   var patients = db.patients.Where(a => a.nurse_patient.Select(x => x.n_id).Equals(p)).ToList();
   return View(patients);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var patients = db.nurse_patient.Where(e => e.nurse.id == nid).Select(e => e.patient).ToList();
```

This solved it. Thanks